# How can I create a custom parameter binding for a claim?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to be able to provide a claim from the current user directly in the parameters of a controller. So that I can write unit tests without touching the ClaimPrincipal magic.

Like the [FromUri] or [FromBody], maybe [FromClaim]?

I tried implementing a CustomModelProvider as specified in this documentation from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2

But I do not know how can I provide the ClaimsPrincipal or List.
Also the ValueProvider returns a string, so I am unsure that this is actually feasible.

This is my attempt of a ClaimModelBinder

```cs
public class ClaimModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));

        var modelName = bindingContext.ModelName;

        // Try to fetch the value of the argument by name
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(modelName);

        if (valueProviderResult == ValueProviderResult.None) return Task.CompletedTask;

        bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(modelName, valueProviderResult);

        var value = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;

        // TODO: Unsure, how to continue after this.

        // Check if the argument value is null or empty
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return Task.CompletedTask;

        int id = 0;
        if (!int.TryParse(value, out id))
        {
            // Non-integer arguments result in model state errors
            bindingContext.ModelState.TryAddModelError(
                                    modelName,
                                    "Author Id must be an integer.");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        // Model will be null if not found, including for 
        // out of range id values (0, -3, etc.)
        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(null);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: From the description at the top, this sounds like a bit of an XY scenario where you are trying to solve one problem with a solution intended to solve a different problem. There is no "magic" involved in ClaimsPrincipal, in fact constructing a ClaimsPrincipal for testing is far easier and more correct than what you are trying to do here. If you actually want go through with the above, you can inject a `IHttpContextAccessor` and access the principal associated with the request but that's a roundabout way of just typing `User.Claims` inside the action

Comment: Mmmmm I though moving system related dependencies to the parameters was a way of getting away with this. As popping the dependency with DateTime all the way up helps make the unit test more clear.
Can you provide a source for "constructing a ClaimsPrincipal for testing is far easier and more correct than what you are trying to do"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can you provide a source for "constructing a ClaimsPrincipal for testing is far easier and more correct than what you are trying to do"?

The source is me. As to why I said it, it's based on the  understanding of [how the ASP NET Core framework is written](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/tree/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src), as I demonstrate below.

To answer your question, Controller has a User property to access claims, there is no need to write a Model Binder to access claims when there is already a User property, unless of course you cannot access claims from that User property due to your claims logic being different. But you haven't made such mentions.

> "I want to be able to provide a claim from the current user directly in the parameters of a controller. So that I can write unit tests without touching the ClaimPrincipal magic."

I interpreted this as,

> "I want to write unit tests for my controller that has logic involving the Claims Principal but I do not know how to provide a fake Claims Principal so I'm going to avoid that and pass a method parameter instead"

The ClaimsPrincipal can be unmagiced as follows.

- `Controller` has a `User` property but it is Get only. **Magic**
- `HttpContext` has a `User` property that is Get and Set (**Nice**) but `Controller.HttpContext` is Get only (**Not So Nice**)
- `Controller` has a `ControllerContext` property which is Get and Set, `ControllerContext` has a `HttpContext` property which is Get and Set. **Jackpot!**

This is the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ControllerBase.cs#L195) of `ControllerBase` which is what `Controller` and `ApiController` derive from,

```
public abstract class ControllerBase
{
    /* simplified below */
    public ControllerContext ControllerContext
    {
            get => _controllerContext;
            set => _controllerContext = value;
    }
    /* ... */
    public HttpContext HttpContext => ControllerContext.HttpContext;
    /* ... */
    public ClaimsPrincipal User => HttpContext?.User;
}
```

As you see here, the User you access is a convenience Getter that ultimately accesses `ControllerContext.HttpContext.User`. Knowing this information, you can unit test a controller that uses a ClaimsPrincipal as follows.

```
// Create a principal according to your requirements, following is exemplary
var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new []
{
    // you might have to use ClaimTypes.Name even for JWTs issued as sub.
    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, "1234"), 
    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iss, "www.example.com"),
}, "Bearer"));

var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
httpContext.User = principal;

// Fake anything you want
httpContext.Request.Headers = /* ... */

var controller = new ControllerUnderTest(...);
controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext();
controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext = httpContext;

// Test the action, no need to pass claims as parameters because the User property is set
var result = controller.ActionThatUsesUserClaims(...);
Assert.Something(result, expected);
```

This is how ASP NET Core works every time a a real web request is received. It literally does the above to make the controller functional and ready for you to use.

All of the above are part of the **public** ASP NET Core api and are not subject to breaking changes without a major version bumb so they are safe to use. In fact, this is one of the things that set ASP Net Core apart from the old ASP NET MVC which was a nightmare to test as it did not expose any of the above publicly.

Having said all this, for some reason I have overlooked, if you really need to write a model binder to provide claims, inject the [HTTPContextAccessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-2.2). But that requires you to check the type of the method parameters and branch execution. One branch would bind properties from the value provider while the other binds from the HttpContext. But why bother when you can do the above with 0 refactoring?

Comment: Thank you. I prefer much more avoiding making a mess of the code, and this well explained solution solves two problems at once; solves the problem itself and also shows the logic behind it.